# Dicionário para objetos em Python

Tags: python, array, matriz, objetos, dicionário

Gostaria de saber como poderei fazer para atribuir um dicionário à um conjunto de objetos.

Por exemplo, tenho um vetor 4x4 de objetos 'neurônios':

`[[<__main__.Neuronio object at 0x1035644e0>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x103564518>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x103564550>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x103564588>], [<__main__.Neuronio object at 0x1035645c0>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x1035645f8>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x103564630>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x103564668>], [<__main__.Neuronio object at 0x1035646a0>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x1035646d8>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x103564710>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x103564748>], [<__main__.Neuronio object at 0x103564780>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x1035647b8>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x1035647f0>, <__main__.Neuronio object at 0x103564828>]]`

E gostaria de trabalhar com dicionário respectivo como se ao trabalhar com o dicionário ('1') teria referenciado o mapa[0][0], objeto <**main**.Neuronio object at 0x1035644e0> e assim consecutivamente para dicionário (2...3...n) referenciando os objetos da matriz.

Answer (score 2):

Começo por dizer que `for elemento in len(range(iteravel))` é sempre a forma errada de iterar em python. O correto é utilizar `for elemento in iteravel`, ou em casos que precisa do indice pode utilizar a função [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for indice, elemento in enumerate(iteravel):
```

Mas no seu caso não precisa do indice, pois apenas está a atribuir com base no `contador`. Então basta fazer assim:

```
dicionario_mapa = {}
contador = 1

for linha in mapa:
    for valor in linha:
        dicionario_mapa[contador] = valor
        contador += 1

print(dicionario_mapa)
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/zSvg7X)

Outra solução interessante seria utilizando [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) de `itertools`, que permite juntar vários iteráveis num só, como que já ficando com uma lista única ao invés de listas de listas. Depois com a função enumerate consegue obter a posição que pretende sem ter que utilizar a variável `contador`:

```
from itertools import chain
dicionario_mapa = {}
for posicao, valor in enumerate(chain(*mapa)):
    dicionario_mapa[posicao + 1] = valor

print(dicionario_mapa)
```

[Veja também esta versão no Ideone](https://ideone.com/d3lWAR)

Uma veja que apenas tem agora uma atribuição no `for`, consegue também tornar isto em [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), ficando apenas uma linha a parte a atribuição dos valores:

```
from itertools import chain
dicionario_mapa = { posicao+1: valor for posicao, valor in enumerate(chain(*mapa)) }

print(dicionario_mapa)
```

[Veja esta ultima versão no Ideone](https://ideone.com/wjbsBq)